Typegoose how to pass generic Class or Model as function parameter
suppose I have this two schema defined:
import { prop, getModelForClass, type Ref, ReturnModelType } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

class User {
  @prop({ required: true, trim: true })
  public email!: string;

  @prop({ trim: true })
  public firstName?: string;

  @prop({ trim: true })
  public lastName?: string;

  @prop()
  public lastUpdate?: Date;

  // just for demo
  public static method1() {
    return true;
  }
}

export const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);


class Ticket {
  @prop({ required: true, ref: () => User })
  public user!: Ref<User>;

  @prop()
  public dateOpen?: Date;

  @prop({ trim: true })
  public message?: string;

  @prop()
  public lastUpdate?: Date;

  // just for demo
  public static method1() {
    return false;
  }
}

export const TicketModel = getModelForClass(Ticket);

I need to write a generic function that accepts Model and Class as parameter, and manipulate some data. Something like this:
const genericFunction = <T>(updDocData: Partial<T>, dataClass: T): Partial<T> => {
  if (dataClass.method1 && typeof dataClass.method1 === 'function' && dataClass.method1() && dataClass.lastUpdate) {
    updDocData.lastUpdate = new Date();
  }

  return updDocData;
}

// demo use
let dataToUpdateForUser = genericFunction<User>({firstName: "updatedName"}, User);
let dataToUpdateForTicket = genericFunction<Ticket>({message: "updatedMessage"}, Ticket);

I'm getting a huge amount of typescript errors:

Property 'method1' does not exist on type 'T'
Property 'lastUpdate' does not exist on type 'Partial'
Argument of type 'typeof User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
Property 'email' is missing in type 'typeof User' but required in type 'User'.

I can't figure out how to pass "User" or "Ticket" class (not an instance) to my generic function. I can't know in advance if the lastUpdate property exists, nor method1 . This are check I have to do inside the function.
I've tried with some types like ReturnModelType or DocumentType but without success.
What am I missing?


Property 'method1' does not exist on type 'T'
Property 'lastUpdate' does not exist on type 'Partial'

You will have to constrict T to have those properties, for example with a custom interface (see example below).

Argument of type 'typeof User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'. Property 'email' is missing in type 'typeof User' but required in type 'User'.

Typescript is unintuitive here, the type of a class (in this case User) is the instance type, not the static type, so you will get a compile error if you do const t: User = User, but const t: User = new User() will work.
For more also read the typegoose documentation Difference between value and type.

I am not entirely sure what you want to accomplish with your function as it has a logic problem:
You want to take in the typegoose class and execute a static method(method1) and then check a instance property(lastUpdate) on that same value, but it is not a instance. Additionally it is likely you dont actually want to call it on the class but on the model instead (in this case UserModel).
Because of that problem I did my best to come up with a more likely case, if the following code is not what you search for please clarify what inputs you want and what properties will be available there.
Anyway, here is the code:
// NodeJS: 22.2.0
// MongoDB: 5.0 (Docker)
// Typescript 5.3.3
import { DocumentType, Ref, getModelForClass, prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose'; // @typegoose/typegoose@12.5.0
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'; // mongoose@8.4.1

interface MaybeUpdateable {
  method1?(): boolean;
  lastUpdate?: Date;
}

class User {
  @prop({ required: true, trim: true })
  public email!: string;

  @prop({ trim: true })
  public firstName?: string;

  @prop({ trim: true })
  public lastName?: string;

  @prop()
  public lastUpdate?: Date;

  public method1() {
    return true;
  }
}

export const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);

class Ticket {
  @prop({ required: true, ref: () => User })
  public user!: Ref<User>;

  @prop()
  public dateOpen?: Date;

  @prop({ trim: true })
  public message?: string;

  @prop()
  public lastUpdate?: Date;

  public method1() {
    return false;
  }
}

export const TicketModel = getModelForClass(Ticket);

interface MaybeLastUpdate {
  lastUpdate?: MaybeUpdateable['lastUpdate'];
}

function genericFunction<T extends MaybeLastUpdate, D extends mongoose.Document & MaybeUpdateable>(
  updDocData: T,
  dataDoc: D
): T & MaybeLastUpdate {
  if (dataDoc.method1 && typeof dataDoc.method1 === 'function' && dataDoc.method1() && dataDoc.lastUpdate) {
    updDocData.lastUpdate = new Date();
  }

  return updDocData;
}

const userDoc = new UserModel();
const ticketDoc = new TicketModel();

const dataToUpdateForUser = genericFunction<Partial<User>, DocumentType<User>>({ firstName: 'updatedName' }, userDoc);
const dataToUpdateForTicket = genericFunction<Partial<Ticket>, DocumentType<Ticket>>({ message: 'updatedMessage' }, ticketDoc);

console.log('dataToUpdateForUser', dataToUpdateForUser);
console.log('dataToUpdateForTicket', dataToUpdateForTicket);

(This code is also available in a typegoose-testing branch)
Note: this code could likely be cleaned-up more depending on what is actually wanted from the function
